# I installed 2 macOS on APFS. the problem is the macOS-1 relate to the second partition files

Tags: partition, apfs

For example :
if I want to open "books" application from the first macOS installed,
I can see :
"Books 1.4" <---Big Sur.
"Books 1.3" <---Catalina.

How can I "tell" the macOS of Big Sur to ignore everything on the second partition.

I read something about hiding the second partition,
but I want to be 10000% sure what I'm doing (trauma from the past)

I prefer elegant solution that tell the macOS:
"hey, all your files are just in this partition, ignore other partitions"

Here is how I can see the Catalina volume from the Big Sur.
[image]

Comment: Can't you just unmount the Catalina partition from within Big Sur? How are your disks/partitions layed out?

Comment: I just read the word "umount" and it's scares me, like it's the "uncle" of format.
It's simple 225GB SDD with 2 volumes(partitions?) on AFPS.
on each volume/partition I have macOS installed and I switch between them in startup disk preferences.

Can you explain in details what I need to do, and what is actually it's doing ?
I know it's probably very simple, but I'm afraid to do mistake. tnx

Comment: btw. I have in Finder "eject" on that volume. but again, I'm not sure EXACTLY what this mean (like USB ejecting ?)

Comment: unmount is basically techspeak for eject :-)

Comment: Asking before doing "eject": After I "eject", how can I "connect" back if I want ? (reverse the operation), Will I still see the -2- volumes  on "startup disk" after "eject" ?

Comment: It depends (on several config options), in the worst case you need to reboot.

Comment: I did "eject".
but then the Big Sur still show the app from the Catalina, but without icon.

So, I wonder, what cause the Big Sur to "see" the Catalina partition and know app from there ?  cause "eject" is not enough.
If I restart , it's "connect" again to the partition.

Comment: It doesn’t see the content of the partition any longer, but the database with all the applications is still here. There should be a Q&A on the site about rebuilding that database.

Comment: For preventing the partition to get mounted at all, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=Prevent+mounting+of+partition+

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't need any of the files on the Catalina partition you can just eject it from Finder.

Comment: I did "eject". but then the Big Sur still show the app from the Catalina, but without icon. So, I wonder, what cause the Big Sur to "see" the Catalina partition and know app from there ? cause "eject" is not enough. If I restart , it's "connect" again to the partition